# Washing machine pipes frozen with water and load still inside

Tags: plumbing

My washing machine stopped while on draining cycle because of frozen pipes. I cannot unhook the machine because of too much water still being inside it. I've poured RV anti-freeze into the pipes inside the wall but cannot get to the pipes inside the washing machine. This has happened before and resolved once temps warmed up but I fear my machine may get damaged if water remains in it. The water inside isn't frozen, it just won't drain for reasons stated above.

Comment: I don't think the washing machine would be damaged if it remains full of water. I assume the machine is in a paused state. If you turn it to OFF, the door would probably release. Then to get it to empty the water, I think you might turn it ON and select a spin only cycle which would probably cause it to drain the drum before spinning. Use low speed spin in case this is a load which retains a lot of water.

Comment: If a low speed spin does not remove enough water and the load can be spun at a higher speed, then repeat at a higher speed.

Comment: Poured rv antifreeze into pipes inside the wall??  Please explain.

Comment: Frozen pipes are at risk of bursting even if the rest of the system is fine. Focus first on getting them warmed up, I think. That will solve the other issues

Comment: MadMonty, I poured RV anti-freeze into the area where the hose from the washer enters into the wall. This has been suggested on several sites and someone I spoke to in a store that sells RV anti-freeze when looking for solutions 2 years ago when it first happened. I also read to put RV anti-freeze into the washing machine with nothing in it but water to help clean the lines. I did put a space heater pointed at the rear of the washer for a couple of hours but that didn't help.

Comment: Jim Stewart, the cycle has stopped at the spin/draining process and will not spin. If I turn the dial to the agitate cycle it agitates but again won't spin and drain. It hums when the dial is set at the spin/drain cycle so I assume it's trying to drain but won't because of frozen pipes. I've turned it off because I don't want to ruin the motor. Is it a safe assumption that once it warms up and the pipes thaw it will work? This happened 2 years ago and once it warmed up it worked like normal. II cannot move the washing machine or try to drain it because it's full of water and too heavy.